# Why prestashop is adding a lang particel at the end of a multistore shop url?

Tags: url-rewriting, localization, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, multistore

I have a prestashop 1.6 installation, in multistore mode. I have some stores already running ok, but now I created a 'german' store with /de url, and have the following issue:

- the shop url is something like [www.example.com/de](http://www.example.com/de), visible and saved in admin
- when I navigate to [www.example.com/de](http://www.example.com/de), automatically I'm redirected to [www.example.com/de/it/](http://www.example.com/de/it/)

I really cannot understand the reason why... All the other shops (fr, es) do work properly. This one does not. No way to keep it simply /de. I already setted a default language for it, I just copied all the settings from the other shops, seems all the same. I cannot spot the error. I also regenerated the htaccess. No way. Could you please suggest me why it is behaving that way?

Ah, funny thing: with firefox will go to [www.example.com/de/it/](http://www.example.com/de/it/) as described above, while with chrome will go to [www.example.com/de/de/!!](http://www.example.com/de/de/!!)! No one simply stay [www.example.com/de/](http://www.example.com/de/).

Thank you, regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a check the settings of the german store, probably you have multiple languages enabled / active in **Localization > Languages** and Prestashop , once you reach the shop homepage, performs a 301-redirect to the default language URL (default behaviour with multiple languages and URL rewriting).

About the funny thing : check the **Localization > Localization** setting "*Set language from browser*", this can lead to different language redirects depending of the browser language.